# IE does not like me appending content to a div already containing a header. any workarounds?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, append

```
<div id="descbox"><div id="scripbox"><h1 id="itemname"></h1></div></div>
```

This is the markup and i'm trying to append into #scripbox, after,not inside #itemname.
Previously, I had #itemname outside #scripbox and the append worked in IE 9.

```
var $descbox = $("#scripbox");

desarray[numero].appendTo($descbox);
```

it is appended from an array of bits of text, that were loaded from an xml file, i don't know if this is relevant as like i said it worked when there was no content in #scripbox. hope someone has an answer because removing #itemname will seriously bugger the flow. cheers.

Comment: Why don't you add a `<div class="content">...</div>` after the `h1` and append the data to `$("#scripbox .content")`?

Comment: I have a list in the text that I'm appending, which i need to stay at the bottom of #scripbox, and the header can break into two lines, so the <div class="content"> would need to fill to the bottom of #scripbox, while still being able to move down and resize, so as not to violate the bottom border of #scripbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that's the problem?  This works in IE:

http://jsfiddle.net/UMzn9/

[EDIT]
This worked, but it the `<ul>` didn't show up in jsFiddle.  Maybe you just need to wrap your text with the jQuery object ($) to get access to it's methods.

```
var Text = "<description><p>Jog Derbyshire Dynamos colours and design. Ideal for competing and training and designed for constant cooling and comfort. Special pre-order introductory price for Jog Derbyshire Dynamos members only!</p> <ul><li>100% Micro-Coolmax</li> <li>Lightweight and comfortable</li> </ul></description>";

$(Text).appendTo("#scripbox");
```

Comment: That does work in IE, as does this, http://jsfiddle.net/Tbza3/1/ which in principal should be the same. My text is loaded from an XML file, that might make things dubious, but then it works all the way until I have to append with the header already in there. everything else works perfectly, there's a lot of different places where I'm appending data in the same way, the only difference is that I'm appending after a header, which is also filled in in this way.

Comment: We've shown that appending to a div that contains a header is NOT a problem.  Maybe it's the content of the XML file that is causing the problem.  Or it's not loading the XML correctly.

Comment: You're right it's because i'm using .contents on the xml to grab the <p><ul><li> tags which are in the text. .html() wont work, i assume because we're dealing with xml, and .text() wont grab markup.

Comment: What is the text you are trying to append?

Comment: <description><p>Jog Derbyshire Dynamos colours and design. Ideal for competing and training and designed for constant cooling and comfort. Special pre-order introductory price for Jog Derbyshire Dynamos members only!</p>
<ul><li>100% Micro-Coolmax</li>
<li>Lightweight and comfortable</li>
</ul></description>

Comment: <description> is the xml node

Comment: finally sorted, because IE is poor, i couldn't call with the contents() method. So I put the xml sections containing markup i was trying to drop into place into <![CDATA[...]]> and used .text() because ie can deal with that.